# Magento magento_default_pages_tmp objectID(10) too big?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, object, autocomplete, algolia

I'm trying to use Algolia in Magento for autocomplete search. It tell me that this object is too big.. Now I'm not interested to algolia working or not. My interest is to understand what is this object. Where I can find it? What is it?

Comment: objectID is the key an algolia index. The _tmp index suffix is used when rebuilding an index, so that the out of date index can be used while the new one is prepared. They offer support on github https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-magento